# Custom DisplayName

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

Currently I am trying to set dynamic the `DisplayName` of a property but I cannot find a way how get information of current property inside an attribute.

This is what I want to achieve:

**Desired Outcome**

[image: Custom Display Name in Label and Required error message]

**My Attribute**

```
public class DisplayNameFromPropertyAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public DisplayNameFromPropertyAttribute(string propertyName) 
        : base(GetDisplayName(propertyName))
    {
    }

    private string GetDisplayBame(string propertyName)
    {
        // Get the value from the given property
    }
}
```

**My Model**

I am trying to read the value from `MyDisplayName` into my custom `DisplayNameFromProperty` attribute

```
public class MyAwesomeModel
{
    public string MyDisplayName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayNameFromProperty("MyDisplayName")]
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

**My Page**

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyValue)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyValue)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyValue)
```

### Question

- Currently I cannot find any reference on internet doing the same. Can someone help me out?
- If this is not possible: What are the alternatives to achieve same result?

  - The `ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` validation attributes should use my custom display name
  - The `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyValue)` should use my custom display name

Comment: Yes you can, I've written an implementation that does exactly what you are doing for labels,  

 I'll hunt out what I've got and then post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cusom HTML extension method that lets you do @Html.DictionaryLabelFor(x=>x.Property) and pull it from a dictionary

```
    public static IHtmlString DictionaryLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string text = null, string prefix = null)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        var displayName = metadata.DisplayName;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            // Your code to get the label via reflection
            // of the object
            string labelText = ""; 

            return html.Label(prefix + metadata.PropertyName, labelText);
        }
        else
        {
            return html.Label(prefix + metadata.PropertyName, text);
        }
    }
```

Overriding the properties on this works, only thing missing is the custom html attributes which wasn't needed when I wrote it

The validation error message is slightly different, you should always write custom errors for these fields so you can rely on them in a resx, you look at the modelstate for the (prefix + key) to get the errors, then get the translated value for each case.

You're best avoiding overwriting the standard HTML call as you'll be making excess calls where not needed elsewhere.

When you have that working and **understand** it the error messages section is pretty trivial to write in yourself, depends how you want to do the formatting on errors. I'm not writing it in as it's basically doing everything for you and if you don't understand how it works you'll be SOL when it comes to writing further extensions

Comment: You don't actually need to write it in either for a label you can do
@Html.Label("MyValue", Model.MyDisplayName)
for the labels, the method above is just a bit cleaner to read

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it isn't solving my problem. The important part in my question is that the `ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName()` result is reflected in many controls (`@Html.LabelFor`, `@Html.TextBoxFor`, `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`, ...). Using my attribute I want to manipulate the result of this method (`[DisplayName("My Display Name")]` also manipulates the result of the method and all controls will automatically take over this defined display name. All other approaches will cause that (for example `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`) will not show correct DisplayName

Comment: So you want to overload the core HtmlHelper functionality so you are calling
     @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.MyValue)
instead of 
     @Html.DictionaryLabelFor(x=>x.MyValue) ?

Comment: Well you are partially right.. if my `GetDisplayName(string propertyname)` returns `"Hello Property: " + propertyName`.. All controls will out of the box show `Hello Property: Text` as Label, `The Hello Property: Text field is required` as Validation Message. I would like same behaviour only now I want to get the value from another property reflected in my display name

Comment: The point is you do not use those methods, but instead write your own calls that aren't relying on the call that get the displayname, you can use @Html.Label("propertyname", "label text") to display the properties but the helper I wrote above does exactly that for you without writing a recursive call in every field in every form it's used in

Comment: You are right.. I can do `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyValue, Model.MyDisplayName)` but unfortunately I cannot do `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyValue, **Model.MyDisplayName**)` Which means my error message will still be `The MyValue field is required` instead of `The MyCustomDisplayNameIWantToUse field is required`

Comment: Do you understand how the Html.ValidationMessageFor method works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57841/discussion-between-hwcverwe-and-finman).